# Showing error of unserialize when run upgrade command in Magento2.2.3

Tags: magento2.2.3

> InvalidArgumentException: Unable to unserialize value. in /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php:39 Stack trace: #0 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Data/Scoped.php(116): Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->unserialize('a:132:{s:22:"sa...') #1 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Data/Scoped.php(96): Magento\Framework\Config\Data\Scoped->_loadScopedData() #2 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Config.php(37): Magento\Framework\Config\Data\Scoped->get('entity_manager_...', Array) #3 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(58): Magento\Framework\Event\Config->getObservers('entity_manager_...') #4 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('entity_manager_...', Array) #5 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EventManager.php(63): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('entity_manager_...', Array) #6 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read.php(96): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EventManager->dispatch('entity_manager_...', Array) #7 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Read->execute(Object(Mirasvit\SearchReport\Model\Log), '0', Array) #8 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/mirasvit/module-search-report/src/SearchReport/Repository/LogRepository.php(60): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->load(Object(Mirasvit\SearchReport\Model\Log), '0') #9 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/mirasvit/module-search-report/src/SearchReport/Service/LogService.php(74): Mirasvit\SearchReport\Repository\LogRepository->get('0') #10 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/mirasvit/module-search-report/src/SearchReport/Plugin/ResponsePlugin.php(96): Mirasvit\SearchReport\Service\LogService->logClick('0') #11 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Mirasvit\SearchReport\Plugin\ResponsePlugin->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor)) #12 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}() #13 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array) #14 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(185): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse() #15 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(156): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(InvalidArgumentException)) #16 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(InvalidArgumentException)) #17 /chroot/home/discount/m223.com/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http)) #18 {main}

Comment: what error in Mirasvit ?

Comment: first try to disable the mirasvit extension - and then check

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the extension you are using and it's throwing that error is not compatible with 2.2.3.
In versions previous to 2.2 (may be previous to 2.1) magento used `serialize` to keep serialized values in different tables.
In 2.2, the format changed from serialized to json.
MOst probably that value comes from the db.
If you find it you can replace it with a json format one.
You can get the json value like this:

```
$dbvalue = '... your value from db here';
$newValue = json_encode(unserialize($dbvalue));
```

Comment: YES, I UPLOADED FRESH MODULE ON MAGENTO VERSION 2.2.3 AND
THIS IS WORKING NOW!